# How to improve Jquery Widgets written in CoffeeScript?

Tags: jquery, widget, coffeescript

My Goal:
Learn CoffeeScript by porting a jquery widget to coffescript.

Following the excellent jQuery widget introduction, I have ported the example code to CoffeeScript:
http://bililite.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/

from:

```
var Green5  = {
    getLevel: function () { return this.options.level; },
    setLevel: function (x) {
        var greenlevels = this.options.greenlevels;
        var level = Math.floor(Math.min(greenlevels.length-1, Math.max(0,x)));
        this.options.level = level;
        this.element.css({background: greenlevels[level]});
        this._trigger('change', 0, level);
    },
    _init: function() { this.setLevel(this.getLevel()); }, // grab the default value and use it
    darker: function() { this.setLevel(this.getLevel()-1); },
    lighter: function() { this.setLevel(this.getLevel()+1); },
    off: function() {
        this.element.css({background: 'none'});
        this._trigger('done');
        this.destroy(); // use the predefined function
    },
    options: {
        level: 15,
        greenlevels: ['#000','#010','#020','#030','#040','#050','#060','#070','#080','#090','#0a0','#0b0','#0c0','#0d0','#0e0','#0f0', '#fff']
    }
};
$.widget("ui.green5", Green5);
```

to:

```
Green5 =
    getLevel: -> @options.level
    setLevel: (x) ->
        greenlevels = @options.greenlevels;
        level = Math.floor(Math.min(greenlevels.length-1, Math.max(0,x)));
        @options.level = level;
        @element.css({background: greenlevels[level]});
        @_trigger('change', 0, level);
    _init: -> @setLevel(@getLevel()) # grab the default value and use it
    darker: -> @setLevel(@getLevel()-1)
    lighter: -> @setLevel(@getLevel()+1)
    off: ->
        @element.css({background: 'none'})
        @_trigger('done')
        @destroy() # use the predefined function
    options: {
        level: 15,
        greenlevels:['#000','#010','#020','#030','#040','#050','#060','#070','#080','#090','#0a0','#0b0','#0c0','#0d0','#0e0','#0f0', '#fff']
    }

$.widget("ui.green5", Green5);
```

It works perfectly fine, but It was so easy to port that I´ve got the feeling I haven´t gotten CoffeeScript yet. How would you improve on that code?

update (thanks to Billy!):

```
Green5 =
    getLevel: -> @options.level
    setLevel: (x) ->
        greenlevels = @options.greenlevels
        level = Math.floor(Math.min(greenlevels.length-1, Math.max(0,x)));
        @options.level = level;
        @element.css
            background: greenlevels[level]
        @_trigger('change', 0, level)
    _init: -> @setLevel @getLevel() # grab the default value and use it
    darker: -> @setLevel @getLevel() - 1 
    lighter: -> @setLevel @getLevel() + 1
    off: ->
        @element.css
            background: 'none'
        @_trigger 'done'
        @destroy() # use the predefined function
    options: {
        level: 15,
        greenlevels:['#000','#010','#020','#030','#040','#050','#060','#070','#080','#090','#0a0','#0b0','#0c0','#0d0','#0e0','#0f0', '#fff']
    }

$.widget "ui.green5", Green5
```

Comment: Could you be more specific and elaborate on what specifically makes you feel unconfortable about this code? Less subjective questions are prefered here on SO.

Comment: I´d want the code to be as easy to read and clean as possible.

So my more specific questions would be: Is there a way to make the code easier to read?

Comment: PS: I´ve found a nice tool to help translating JS to CS: http://ricostacruz.com/js2coffee/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get rid of semi-colons at the end, and also get rid of a ton of brackets and curly braces.

```
Green5 =
    getLevel: -> @options.level
    setLevel: (x) ->
        greenlevels = @options.greenlevels;
        level = Math.floor Math.min greenlevels.length-1, Math.max 0,x
        @options.level = level
        @element.css background: greenlevels[level]
        @_trigger 'change', 0, level
    _init: -> @setLevel this.getLevel() # grab the default value and use it
    darker: -> @setLevel this.getLevel() - 1
    lighter: -> @setLevel this.getLevel() + 1
    off: ->
        @element.css background: 'none'
        @_trigger 'done'
        @destroy() # use the predefined function
    options: level: 15, greenlevels: ['#000','#010','#020','#030','#040','#050','#060','#070','#080','#090','#0a0','#0b0','#0c0','#0d0','#0e0','#0f0', '#fff']

$.widget "ui.green5", Green5
```

However, the syntactic sugar is not the only benefit of CoffeeScript. A big plus is the way it re-writes certain code structures into better javascript.

For example:

```
yearsOld = max: 10, ida: 9, tim: 11

ages = for child, age of yearsOld
  child + " is " + age
```

Becomes:

```
var age, ages, child, yearsOld;
yearsOld = {
  max: 10,
  ida: 9,
  tim: 11
};
ages = (function() {
  var _results;
  _results = [];
  for (child in yearsOld) {
    age = yearsOld[child];
    _results.push(child + " is " + age);
  }
  return _results;
})();
```

Where the variables are all declared properly, and a closure is automatically added around the `ages for loop` which is written with good javascript technique that is honestly quite awkward to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I certainly like the ruby-ness of CoffeeScript - It´s a concept that really draws me to it.

I´m using it currently in combination with require.js - The combination of jQuery, require.js and CoffeeScript seems a really nice way to build WebApps. The last year I was working with GWT, but each time ended up finding some jQuery things I wanted to include - and I was missing the "lightness" of this solution.

Comment: Yeah - the web is changing right? Rock 'n' Roll! The biggest revelation for me this year is the explosion of JavaScript into new contexts. Cross platform development via projects like Titanium and also server side JavaScript via projects like Node.js.

Comment: Yea, I love it. Especially that "normal", light web development seems to evolve so much that it´s on par with heavier frameworks like GWT or google closure. I just checked out Titanium for the first time. Looks good. Thanks for the tipp.